# change horizontal center and width of responsive image

Tags: html, css

I have a 3051 x 1716 pixel image.

[image]

When in mobile I want to view it like the following without cropping the image and uploading it second time:

[image]

I mean I just want to change the horizontal center of the image and change the width according to sceensize given it is a mobile screen.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use srcset and sizes and let the browser load the right (and smaller) image for smaller, portrait screens?

Comment: You can make use of object-fit CSS property. I have created a pen for this, you can check this out if this helps.
https://codepen.io/vinu_pen/pen/ExNMRGr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a media query on a background-image like below, but its actually not best practice: only load what you really need on mobile devices to get faster pageloads. And don't use background images to display important content... so you might wanna look into using the picture tag and responsive images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

However, if two seperate image files are not an option, here is a solution:

```css
.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615731364858-99013ac4fad3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { // set to your mobile view breakpoint
  .container {
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; // or whatever height you want
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. If you will take an image as a background image then you will be able to set the position of the image as per your requirement. We have used `background-size` and `background-position` properties to adjust the image.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/xhsb7ocL/3/

```css
.banner-bg {
  background: no-repeat center center / auto 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .banner-bg {
    background-position: left center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-bg" style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Wi7m.jpg')">
</div>
```